# Vuetify sparkline throws Error "Cannot read property 'getTotalLength' of undefined"

Tags: charts, vuetify.js, uicomponents

I want to have a simple sparkline in nuxt, but in the browser (chrome), in the console this error loged: [ERROR] [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTotalLength' of undefined"

What I see in the browser is the chart draws once and then it disappears.

I almost sure that this error is due to auto-draw property. It is because, I changed other properties and nothing happened until I removed auto-draw and the error was gone.

```
<v-sparkline
      auto-draw
      :value="value"
    ></v-sparkline>
```

In the script section, here is the value:

```
 data: () => ({
value: [100, 200, 300]
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is to set auto-draw on mounted:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-sparkline
        :value="value"
        :auto-draw="myAutoDraw"
      ></v-sparkline>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

and

```
data: () => ({
  value: [100, 200, 300],
  myAutoDraw: false,
}),
mounted() {
  this.myAutoDraw = true
}
```

The sparkline component includes:

```
watch: {
  value: {
    immediate: true,
    handler () {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        if (!this.autoDraw || this.type === 'bar') return

          const path = this.$refs.path
          const length = path.getTotalLength()
```

I don't think that this.$refs.path exists until after mounted() has run.

Comment: I'm sorry for the tardy answer. in this [link](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101), the sparkline works well such as the code in my question. I tried your solution and the mentioned error does not appear in the console, but the chart still disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing your error without success.
If you could provide some more context or try to reproduce your error in a codepen that would be helpful.

Here is a *working* codepen of your use case:
https://codepen.io/maxkoi/pen/Jqawjy

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-sparkline
        :value="value"
        auto-draw
      ></v-sparkline>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    value: [100, 200, 300]
  })
})
```

Comment: I had tried these [samples](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/sparklines) in codepen and as you said it works well. However, in [my-project](https://github.com/nargesmomenyan/nuxt-vuetify-project/tree/master/pages/_lang) it doesn't. you could see it in the report.vue page.

Answer (score 0):

Use v-if to draw v-sparkline

```
<v-sparkline v-if="timeToDraw"
                :value="value"
                :gradient="gradient"
                smooth="10"
                stroke-linecap="round"
                gradient-direction="top"
                auto-draw="false"
                type="trend"
            ></v-sparkline>
```

and

```
mounted(){
    this.timeToDraw = true;
}
```

Then v-sparkline will be appear after vue is mounted

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily answering the OP's problem, but maybe it helps someone else stumbling upon this problem.

I got the same error message when my value array had only had a length of 1.

Throws error:

```
<v-sparkline
   :value="[1]"
></v-sparkline>
```

Works:

```
<v-sparkline
   :value="[1,2]"
></v-sparkline>
```

If that might be your issue, just make sure that you only render the sparkline when your array has a length of 2+.

```
<v-sparkline
   v-if="data.length > 1"
   :value="data"
></v-sparkline>
```